# Listening to a jms queue and processing only 10 messages at a time

Tags: java, multithreading, jms

I have a javax.jms.Queue queue and have my listener listening to this queue. I get the message(a String) and execute a process passing the string as an input parameter to that process.

I want to just run 10 instances of that process running at one time. Once those are finished then only next messages should be processed.

How it can be achieved? As it reads all the message at once and runs as many instances of that process running, causing the server to be hanged.

```
// using javax.jms.MessageListener
message = consumer.receive(5000); 
if (message != null) { 
    try { 
        handler.onMessage(message);  //handler is MessageListener instance
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code where your listener pulls messages and puts them into the processes.

Comment: I am using javax.jms.MessageListener.

message = consumer.receive(5000);
if (message != null) {
   try {
    handler.onMessage(message);
}
handler is MessageListener instance.

Comment: Is your process executing on a thread, or on another JVM/native/whatever process?

Comment: It is actually running on another JVM. There is an executable actually that I run and it accepts the string as a parameter that I get from the jms queue. Now I want that only 10 instances of that exe should be running at a time, once those 10 are finished working, next messages should be procesed and so on.

Comment: Do you get an indication of when an external processes terminates or when all ten processes have terminated (successfully/unsuccessfully), and how is this message delivered / processed?  Does this have to be done in batches of ten, or can you instead initiate a new process as soon as another process terminates instead of waiting for all ten processes to terminate?

Comment: Yes, I want to run 10 processes regardless of the other processes are finished or not. The thing is there should be a maximum of 10 processes or less running at a time. Once these are finished, It will process the other messages in the queue. And also what I noticed that my queue listener just retrieves all the messages at once and it turn creates same number of instances of the exe.

Answer (score 1):

Try to put this annotation on your mdb listener:

```
@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "maxSession", propertyValue = "10")
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. However I do not have any MDBListenere. I am manually making a connection to the queue.

Comment: I am using javax.jms.MessageListener, as soon as there is a message in the queue, I execute my process.

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple `while` check would suffice. Here's some Pseudocode.

```
While (running processes are less than 10) {
    add one to the running processes list
    do something with the message
}
```

and in the code for `onMessage`:

```
function declaration of on Message(Parameters) {
    do something
    subtract 1 from the running processes list
}
```

Make sure that the variable you're using to count the amount of running processes is declared as `volatile`.

Example as requested:

```
public static volatile int numOfProcesses = 0;

while (true) {
    if (numOfProcesses < 10) {
        // read a message and make a new process, etc
        // probably put your receive code here
        numOfProcesses++;
    }
}
```

Wherever your the code for your processes is written:

```
// do stuff, do stuff, do more stuff
// finished stuff
numOfProcesses--;
```

Comment: Is it possible that I can limit my Consumer to consume only few messages at a time. Right now it just consumes all the messages at once. Do you know if it is possible

Comment: @user3262365 I've never had this issue before, so I can't say for sure that it's possible, but the alternative would be to limit the messages you're sending instead of limiting the messages in the queue. If you use a synchronized variable combined with sending the messages 10 at a time, you should be able to achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: Could you please elaborate it with some example??

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you have a way of accepting `hasTerminated` messages from your external processes.  This controller thread will communicate with the JMS listener using a [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).  The `Semaphore` is initialized with 10 permits, and every time an external process calls `TerminationController#terminate` (or however the external processes communicate with your listener process) it adds a permit to the `Semaphore`, and then `JMSListener` must first acquire a permit before it can call `messageConsumer.release()` which ensures that no more than ten processes can be active at a time.

```
// created in parent class
private final Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(10);

@Controller
public class TerminationController {
    private final semaphore;

    public TerminationController(Semaphore semaphore) {
        this.semaphore = semaphore;
    }

    // Called from external processes when they terminate
    public void terminate() {
        semaphore.release();
    }
}

public class JMSListener implements Runnable {
    private final MessageConsumer messageConsumer;
    private final Semaphore semaphore;

    public JMSListener(MessageConsumer messageConsumer, Semaphore semaphore) {
        this.messageConsumer = messageConsumer;
        this.semaphore = semaphore;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            semaphore.acquire();
            Message message = messageConsumer.receive();
            // create process from message
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi@Zim-Zam O'Pootertoot Could you elaborate it more with an example?